# How to choose the particular sentences in mysql in php?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

How to choose the particular sentences in mysql in php?

```
$query = "select * from table where title LIKE '%{$java}%'";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query))) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    $title = $row2['title'];

    if ($title ==TOBE== "<pink>$title</pink>") {
            ...........................
            ...........................
            ...........................
    }

}
```

cause i want like this, I search the word "java", and when it appears, only the word java are pink

[image: this image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming `$java` is a variable containing the search term

```
$query = "select * from table where title LIKE '%{$java}%'";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query))) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    $title = $row['title'];

    $title = str_replace($java,"<pink>{$java}</pink>",$title);

}
```

this will replace any occurrence of the search term inside the string with the term wrapped in `<pink>` so

```
"I don't like java programming"
```

will be

```
"I don't like <pink>java</pink> programming"
```

it will also work for this situation

```
"aldfhasdjavaasdkas;ldk"
```

will become

```
"aldfhasd<pink>java</pink>asdkas;ldk"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_replace()` to substitute inside the title.

```
$query = "select * from table where title LIKE '%{$java}%'";
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query))) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    $title = str_replace($java, "<pink>$java</pink>", $row['title']);

    ...    
}
```